# Adding another enemy to a coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[] enemies;

private void Start(){
    StartCoroutine("SpawnHandler");
}
private IEnumerator SpawnHandler(){
    float spawnDelay;
    int thisEnemy = 0;
    int nextEnemy = 1;
    GameObject cachedEnemy;
    GameObject cachedEnemyTwo;
    float dieTime;

    while (thisEnemy < 2)
    {
        spawnDelay = Random.Range(3f,6f); //random time, from 1-3
        dieTime = Random.Range(3f,3f);


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay); //wait that time


        cachedEnemy = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemies[thisEnemy],       transform.position, transform.rotation);//spawn enemy, cache him

        StartCoroutine(Kill(dieTime, cachedEnemy));
        //Somewhere here 
    }
}


private IEnumerator Kill(float wait, GameObject enemy){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
    Destroy(enemy);

    //or here i need to include the "int nextEnemy". I need it to come after the cached enemy so it needs to have the same random.range value!
    // I need it to have the same value so it spawns exactly 1 second after the cached enemy, like a pair so they spawn from the same
    // random value (very important). So as soon as enemy 1 dieTime runs out, "int nextEnemy" spawns and  runs for 1 second after.
}
}
```

The plan is for something like this: int thisEnemy spawns using spawndelay, it runs for 3 seconds (to stick to the example, dieTime). then when this dies spawns nextEnemy for 1 second stright after, THESE MUST BE LIKE PAIRS! then just loop.

Thank you for any help this is really rattling my cage!
Max

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `ive found i need to be much, much more specific in order to get the answer i need` I'm comparing your previous question to this one and I don't see how this is any more specific. Not sure what the problem is or what the question is.

Comment: I need to add the "int nextEnemy" onto the coroutine but like a pair so they both use the same random values. Once thisEnemy dies it needs to spawn the nextEnemy for one second after it. The question, How?

Comment: Maybe its better to give a visual represenatation, easier and maybe simplier to understand. Enemy one spawns does his little battle dance for 3 seconds, then vanishes. strigtht after that i need a flash to happen for one second. It has to be done this way as two sepearate enemies ive tried literally everything. The first enemy is simply an animation which cannot hurt the player, then the flash is where the damage hapens. If that helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
StartCoroutine(Kill(dieTime, cachedEnemy, spawnDelay, cachedEnemyTwo, nextEnemy))// <-- pass needed values to Kill
```

and change the Kill :

```
private IEnumerator Kill(float wait, GameObject enemy, float spawnDelay, GameObject enemy2, int enemyIndex){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
    Destroy(enemy);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay or 1 second what you need...);
    cachedEnemyTwo = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemies[enemyIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

I'm sorry this is how I understood your question and I'm quite new to IEnumerators hope this helps.